# Embedding an Excel workbook in a web page

Tags: html, excel, iframe, embed, onedrive

I'm using Microsoft's One Drive to share an Excel workbook by embedding it into a web page using the iframe tag.

I've got the code that One Drive provides and it displays fine on the page. However, it's possible for a user to click the icon in the black bar at the bottom and view the Workbook full screen.

I don't have a problem with that, but it then gives the option to download, copy and share the entire file and that is a problem.

I've found parameters that can be used with the workbook link such as wdHideGridlines, but is there anything that will get rid of that black bar? Or anything that will stop someone downloading the file?

It seems that you can embed a file with OneDrive and it's open for all, or you can use the 'share' option and get a view-only link, but I can't seem to embed that link - it displays an Excel icon for the workbook rather than a view of the data.

I hope this makes sense, if anyone can help I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, the only way to prevent the download is to hide the download command on the web page with CSS.

Cast your vote in this user voice idea. https://excel.uservoice.com/forums/274580-excel-online/suggestions/19274656-remove-the-download-option
If it gets sufficient votes, Microsoft will consider implementing it.

Comment: Actually, can I be cheeky and ask for a bit of help with the CSS? I've just had a quick browse in Google and not sure what I'm doing - this is going to be way above my level!